# How to connect Mobx6 store to react 15.8 component? 'Uncaught Invariant Violation, Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component''

Tags: javascript, typescript, mobx, mobx-react

I am trying to connect to a mobx store to my react component.

library versions:

```
 "mobx": "^6.3.2"
 "mobx-react": "^7.2.0"
 "react": "16.8.2"
 "react-dom": "16.8.2"
```

Below is the minimal sample code:

**A.tsx**

```
const root_store = new RootStore();

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider root_store={root_store}>
        <IApp></IApp>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

**B.tsx** (for IApp component ^^)

```
interface Props {
    root_store?: RootStore;
}

class App extends React.Component<Props> {
    render(): any {    
        return (
            <div>
                 <IEventsEmbedSkin />
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export const IApp = inject(({root_store}:{root_store:RootStore}) => {
    console.log(root_store);
    return {
        root_store: root_store,
    };
})(observer(App))
```

**C.tsx** (for IEventsEmbedSkin component ^^ )

```
interface Props {
    root_store?: RootStore;
}

class EventsEmbedSkin extends React.Component<Props> {
    
    render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <div></div>
        );
    }
}

export const IEventsEmbedSkin = inject(({root_store}:{root_store:RootStore}) => {
    console.log(root_store);
    return {
        root_store: root_store,
    };
})(observer(EventsEmbedSkin));
```

If I DON'T RENDER `IEventsEmbedSkin` component in file B.tsx (imported from file **C.tsx)**, everything works fine in file B, react responds to any store update. when I Render `IEventsEmbedSkin` component (imported from file **C.tsx**) I get this error:

> **Uncaught Invariant Violation: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.**

> **The above error occurred in the  component:**

> **Uncaught Invariant Violation: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.**

Can anyone help me with what's going on?

I cannot change my react version.

my stores look like this:

**rootstore.tsx**

```
export class RootStore {
    context_store: ContextStore;
    recording_store: RecordingStore;

    constructor(props: Props) {

        this.context_store = new ContextStore({
            root_store: this,
        }); 

        this.recording_store = new RecordingStore({
            root_store: this,
        });
    }
}
```

**contextstore.tsx**:

```
export class ContextStore {
    root_store: RootStore;
    status: 'pending' | 'error' | 'done' | 'debug' = 'debug';

    constructor(props: Props) {
        this.root_store = props.root_store;    

        makeObservable(
            this,
            {
                status: observable,
                initialise: action,
            },
            {
                autoBind: true,
            },
        );
    }

    public async initialise(): Promise<void> {
        this.status = 'pending';
        try {
            const data = await this.api_store.get_config_and_instance_data();

            runInAction(() => {
                this.status = 'done';
            });
        } catch (e) {
            runInAction(() => {
                this.status = 'error';
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `runInAction` looks like a state hook. And, as the error says, you can only call a hook inside a function component.

Comment: Do you know how to convert your class component to a function component?

Comment: @Andy thankyou for your suggestion, I'll try this once without runInAction and get back...

Comment: @Andy the react version i am using doesn't support hooks, I cannot use functional components. I cannot upgrade the react version either because it's not upto me

Comment: You should have a team discussion about upgrading if you're running issues like this.

Comment: upgrading react will require another ~6 months of effort, the project is huge and across 10+ repositories ...

Comment: Upgrading doesn't mean you can't use class components - it just means you can use functional components too. You don't have to rewrite anything.

Comment: Ive removed every mention of runInAction, still ending up with the same error @Andy

Comment: I think this version of mobx use hooks, and I'll have to downgrade to 5?